# When adding images in view pager then white space is coming in place o actiobar is action bar is hidden

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to add images to viewpager but after adding the images white space is coming in place of ActionBar after hiding it. I want that viewpager should be visible in status bar also.
 How to do that and how ot remove that white space.

Below is the code for the same

## MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/nature"
    tools:context="grepthorsoft.com.fullscreenviewpager.MainActivity">
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/li"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="280dp">
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
             android:id="@+id/pager"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="232dp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
         <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
             android:id="@+id/indicator"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="48dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
      </RelativeLayout>



   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    Button b;
    private static final Integer[] XMEN = {R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.nature, R.drawable.nature};
    private ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        for(int i=0;i<XMEN.length;i++)
            XMENArray.add(XMEN[i]);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,XMENArray));
        CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == XMEN.length) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 2500, 2500);
    }



}
```

## MyAdapter.java

```
package grepthorsoft.com.fullscreenviewpager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images=images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        return myImageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
}
```

## style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>


    </style>
```

## slide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: just remove  getSupportActionBar().hide(); And you have declared specific height for view pager. Just make it as match_parent. And do you want full screen?